# d3.js Nice End Ticks Exceeding Domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue where I needed to use `.nice()` on one of my axis scales so that the ticks would make use of the end points and spread out properly (instead of leaving the end points unused).

Now that I fixed that, an unexpected problem has arisen. After I called `.nice()` like so:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width])

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })).nice();
```

The axis now ranges up to the year 2018. This could spell trouble, because it looks very pretentious, as its only Feb. 2017. Obviously I don't have a crystal ball, there is no 2018 in my data anywhere, so my only guess is that the function went overboard when it was interpolating.

I love/literally need the tick spacing interpolating from `.nice()` or something equivalent to that, but at that same time I can't afford to have interpolations out of the domain of my data. Has anyone else had this problem? What can be brought to bear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are between a rock and a hard place.

The problem here is that D3 axis generator (specially when using a time scale) was not created having in mind such customizations.

Let's look at your problem: when using `nice()` you get the end ticks. However, as you said, the end value may exceed the domain, and that's a well known issue.

Here is a demo, the end date is today but the axis goes to 2020:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date("1980-01-01"), new Date()]).range([20,480]).nice();

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0,50)").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="80"></svg>
```

A possible solution is using `concat` with the scale's domain to guarantee that the first and last value in the domain will be the first and last tick, like this:

```
.tickValues(xScale.ticks(10).concat(xScale.domain()))
```

And setting the approximate number of ticks using `ticks`. Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date("1980-01-01"), new Date()]).range([20,480]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).tickValues(xScale.ticks(10).concat(xScale.domain()));

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0,50)").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="80"></svg>
```

However, as you can see, the ticks are not evenly spaced, as you wish.

Thus, an alternative solution for your problem, still using this `concat` approach, is tweaking the `ticks` value until we make the ticks appear to be *more or less* evenly spaced:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date("1980-01-01"), new Date()]).range([20,480]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%Y")).tickValues(xScale.ticks(5).concat(xScale.domain()));

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(0,50)").call(xAxis);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="80"></svg>
```

That being said, this is not a proper *solution*, because I doubt anyone can make (without a cumbersome hack) the axis starting and ending at the exact domain limits **and** having all the ticks evenly spaced .

Comment: That is puzzling isn't it? I thought this was something that would be addressed in v4, but perhaps it's not a big deal to the community as a whole. It does seem to impact my work personally though. At least your work-around will reign the axis labels back into the domain without sacrificing much in terms of aesthetics. Thank you!

Comment: A follow up question for you when you have a moment, when I tried this on a different data set, with domain: `.domain([new Date("2012-01-01"), new Date("2017-01-01")])` What happens is there are two 2017 ticks, but they appear on top of each other and appear bold faced as a result. I recall from one of M. Bostock's post's that there is a certain way to make sure endpoints values are unique. That's just my hunch, I'm actually not sure why this happened.

Comment: Show me a fiddle/plunker/codepen/whatever with this behaviour, please.

Comment: For some reason it's not displaying properly, but I cannot find the cause of the problem. I will keep looking it over, meanwhile you can see the code at least: https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/c3d26a76995c8a278fa0f8abd779ba41. (ps, if you're wondering why I have 2 x axis scales, it's because I cannot figure out how to export dates from my statistics package yet)

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you put it in the `<head>`. I don't have time to see why it's duplicating, but the solution is using `.tickValues(x2Scale.ticks(4).concat(x2Scale.domain()[0]))`.

Comment: You're right, now it's perfect. Thanks a million. For what it's worth, I fixed the index.html, so it should display properly now, and I made the height smaller so the x axis is visible without needing to full screen.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved with D3.js v6. The end tick out of domain issue is easily solved when using `d3.scaleTime()` together with `.nice()`. However, be aware of `d3.scaleUtc()`. When using `d3.scaleUtc()` together with `.nice()`, the same issue persists - so just switch to `d3.scaleTime()`. :)